# Who wrote Shir Hashirim, Koheles and Mishlei?

Tags: tanach

Was it King Shlomo or Chizkiyahu and his colleagues? And when did Chizkiahu live?

Comment: https://www.etzion.org.il/en/tanakh/ketuvim/megillat-shir-hashirim/authorship-shir-hashirim

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89003/11486

Comment: i assume you are referencing the gemara in bava batra which lists king hezekiah and his colleagues as the redactors of those books. redacting and authoring are two different things although similar. traditionally it is accepted that king solomon authored, or at least is the source, for most of the content in those books. the idea that hezekiah compiled them is strengthened by the book of proverbs itself in 25:1. the wisdom of king david can also be found in proverbs as well as that of a king lemuel although the latter is identified as solomon by traditional sources.

Answer (score -2):

The boring answer is that King Solomon wrote these three books.
Then some people will argue the academic view would suggest otherwise.

A wise man will understand that selfhood is not a matter of flesh but a matter of spirit.

The spirit of the Wise King of Israel is the abstract persona which hovers above these texts.

A more advanced answer is that you will have to read them and internalize them and discover it is nothing but your own soul which wrote these books.

I can also suggest that these holy books were spontaneously teleported into your mind from a primordial place.

At the end of the day the universe has one single author and that is what these books will teach you. It is He who ultimately wrote these books into His narrative.